# Como sobrepor Divs sem position absolute e relative? CSS

Tags: css, css3, div, posicionamento

Boa tarde, pessoal, como vão?

Estou procurando uma forma de sobrepor div's sem position absolute e relative, teria como?

se eu usar algum desses, ele acaba vazando para dentro do meu header (que está com a position fixed) quando rolo a pagina.

Alguma sugestão?

Preciso que o elemento2 sobreponha o elemento 1 e 3, fique no meio dos dois, mas sobreposto.

ex: html : `

```
    </head>
    <body>
       <header class='header'> </header>

      <div class="elemento1">a </div>
      <div class="elemento2">b </div>
      <div class="elemento3">c </div>
    </body>``
```

CSS: `.header{ position: fixed; }`

Comment: Tem poucas informações na pergunta para dar uma boa resposta, mas se eu entendi direito você pode usar `transform: translate` e suas variações.

Comment: esse sobrepõe também, Rafael, mas acaba tendo o mesmo efeito do position absolute e relative, ele sobrepõe a header também quando rolo a tela.

Comment: Vc pode usar position absolute e usar z-index na header.

Comment: funcionou, muito obrigado, sam!

Answer (score -3):

Não é o caso nesta pergunta, mas se você tiver uma div dentro de outra div, a div interna pode ser total ou parcialmente mascarada devido a overflow: hidden, use em overflow: visible. Talvez seja uma solução utilizar isso para o seu caso.

Comment: tentei com overflow também, mas não deu certo :/